# Dir-3040 ftp server buffer overflow

Tags: router, ftp

Originally posted on reddit Dir-3040 ftp issue

Dir-3040 latest firmware 1.20b03 with ftp service up and running. Upnp,samba are off. Have no issues uploading small files to usb stick on usb2.0 port. When uploading 400mb file router is rebooting when 35% is uploaded. Tried few times and its exactly at 35%. Cant read syslog because its not saving the log that i need. Thought of power issues so swapped adapter from my other router same issue. As i dont have access to source code of ftp service because of firmware encryption i cant confirm yet if it has buffer overflow issues in ftp service.

Can confirm that its not writting in usb flash till whole file is read which points me to thought of buffer overflow.

Any thoughts?

Update: found what server its running its a stupid-ftpd last update 12 years ago. Can confirm file size of 135mb is enough to crash it. There are bunch of places for buffer overflow.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Change the router. Do not use router as FTP server. Change the USB stick.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely a software algorithm that causes
memory overrun when reading the file into RAM before writing
it out.

Your only solutions would be to update all the
software components to the latest version, and/or inform
D-Link. You don't have many other options.

I found a
[D-Link Support Announcement](https://supportannouncement.us.dlink.com/announcement/publication.aspx?name=SAP10350)
that contains a firmware patch for "Stack-Based Overflow".
It can be downloaded from the link, and it might help (or not).
It is the latest firmware version according to the
[D-Link website](https://support.dlink.com/ProductInfo.aspx?m=DIR-3040-US).

(Note: In several sources I found the remark that the
DIR-3040 has known memory overrun vulnerabilities.)